# How do I properly generate the .pem file(s ?) needed for the grpc java auth example?

Tags: java, ssl, public-key-encryption, pem, grpc

For some background, I am following [this guide](http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html) as I am building up some grpc microservices with auth.

I am attempting to get the very basic java example going, and the keys that I am generating are not allowing the ssl connection to happen.

Here is my server code.

```
server = NettyServer.forPort(8050)
    .useTransportSecurity(
        new File(serverCert)
        new File(serverKey)
    )
    .addService(
        new TestService(); // my implementation of the grpc service
    )
    .build();

server.start();
```

Here is my client code

```
channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8050)
    .sslContext(
        GrpcSslContexts
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(
                new File(serverCert)
            ).build()
    ).build();
```

Now, when I go to generate the key

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

After inputting some information about myself, I end up with 2 files

```
>> ls 
key.pem cert.pem
```

in my code above, serverKey refers to "key.pem" and serverCert refers to "cert.pem"

I am able  to start the server without issue. When I attempt to connect with the client, I get the following error

```
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@6ddf90b0] Created with target localhost:8050
Nov 03, 2016 11:25:16 AM getapi.example.TestClient greet
INFO: Will try to greet world ... 
Nov 03, 2016 11:25:17 AM getapi.example.TestClient greet
WARNING: RPC failed: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem}
Nov 03, 2016 11:25:17 AM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl maybeTerminateChannel
INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@6ddf90b0] Terminated
```

And the most relevant line seems to be this

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
```

I will admit that I basically have no idea about keys/certs/pem files beyond a very basic understanding of public key cryptography.

Could someone shed some light on how to properly generate the key files that grpc is expecting?

Comment: I have an answer that works. I was very close. When I was creating my keys, I used my IP for the common name, and not "localhost". Will answer properly tomorrow when I am able.

Comment: Something looks broken with the SSL setup (not your configuration per se). For example, a different version of tcnative may need to be used. The `cause` of that Status probably has more information. Can you run `status.getCause().printStackTrace()` on the failing status and post the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was creating my keys incorrectly. Here is the openssl command

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

When it asked for the common name, I originally put my IP address. This was not correct.

I can't speak for all use cases, but the appropriate thing to do here was to instead use "localhost"